# my assembly code counts one extra byte for string length

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I have written the following code to read a text and calculate the length and report it. To keep the code simple, I assume the length of string is less than 10 characters.

The code I use for build is

```
nasm -f elf64 strlen.asm && ld strlen.o -o strlen && ./strlen
```

I have two question:

1. This code is compiled as 64-bit while the code itself is 32-bit. What changes should I apply to make this code 64-bits too?
2. Why does the application always report the length one byte extra? Theoretically, it does not count the null termination. Does the given text include `\x10` or `\x13`?

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

; show prompt message
    mov     edx, 19     ; number of bytes to write - one for each letter plus 0Ah (line feed character)
    mov     ecx, txt_prompt    ; move the memory address of our message string into ecx
    mov     ebx, 1      ; write to the STDOUT file
    mov     eax, 4      ; invoke SYS_WRITE (kernel opcode 4)
    int     80h

; read the user input
    mov eax, 3          ; Read user input into str
    mov ebx, 0          ; |
    mov ecx, user_input        ; | <- destination
    mov edx, 100        ; | <- length
    int 80h             ; \

; calculate the length

    mov     ebx, user_input        ; move the address of our message string into EBX
    mov     eax, ebx        ; move the address in EBX into EAX as well (Both now point to the same segment in memory)

strlen_nextchar:
    cmp     byte [eax], 0   ; compare the byte pointed to by EAX at this address against zero (Zero is an end of string delimiter)
    jz      strlen_finished        ; jump (if the zero flagged has been set) to the point in the code labeled 'finished'
    inc     eax             ; increment the address in EAX by one byte (if the zero flagged has NOT been set)
    jmp     strlen_nextchar        ; jump to the point in the code labeled 'strlen_nextchar'

strlen_finished:
    sub     eax, ebx        ; subtract the address in EBX from the address in EAX
    add     byte [txt_output+33], al

; show output message
    mov     edx, 34     ; number of bytes to write - one for each letter plus 0Ah (line feed character)
    mov     ecx, txt_output    ; move the memory address of our message string into ecx
    mov     ebx, 1      ; write to the STDOUT file
    mov     eax, 4      ; invoke SYS_WRITE (kernel opcode 4)
    int     80h

; exit code
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     eax, 1
    int     80h

section .data
txt_prompt:   db      'Enter your message:', 0Ah
txt_output:   db      'The string length is calculated: 0', 0Ah

section .bss
user_input: resb 100
```

Comment: Yes, `read()` returns the end of line character too. You can see that using a debugger. Note it's not `\x10` as that would be hex. It's 10 in decimal.

Comment: For 64-bit, use 64-bit system calls and addressing modes.  And `default rel`.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) has some links.  Note that building it as 64-bit *makes it 64-bit*.  It's just that it happens to also be a valid 64-bit program which happens to work when linked as a Linux non-PIE executable (static addresses in the low 32 bits of virtual address space).  If you had used `push ebx` or something, it wouldn't assemble because that's not a legal 64-bit mode instruction.  Or crash if you used `mov esp, ebp` / ret.

Comment: @Jester, thank you. Which debugger can I use on Ubuntu?

Comment: The stock one is `gdb`, with frontends if you like.

Comment: @Jester, do `nasm` and `gdb` go well together?

Comment: Yeah. Use `nasm -F dwarf`.

Comment: @Jester, thank you. Also, if I the last character is 10, to get a null terminated string, should I loop through it to find the 10 or is there any register which gives me the count of entered character?

Comment: `read()` returns the number of bytes stored into the buffer in `eax`.

Comment: @Jester, is it a Linux specific function??

Comment: No, the man page says it's _"CONFORMING TO SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001"_

Comment: @Jester, is [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) what you are talking about? how do you call it in assembly?

Comment: That is the libc wrapper, but you are already invoking the system call directly. That works the same way, you don't need the function. What I am trying to tell you that at the point `; calculate the length` you already have the length in `eax` (which includes the line feed) so all you need to do is subtract one and you are done.

Comment: @Jester, I think I can solve it in another way. I can count the sentence until I reach character 10. Does it always work?

Comment: If the user's input is longer than 100 characters or `stdin` gets closed then you won't have a line feed in the buffer. Also in the unlikely case that you get a partial read for whatever reason (e.g. reading from a network).

Comment: I am wondering how `scanf` and `iostream` are handling this. It looks like there are a lot of modifications and checks on result.